# Ajuda com cores RGB em Hexadecimal 16bits

Tags: c#, visual-basic-6, hexadecimal, rgb

então, estou criando um editor de um jogo de futebol de PS2 em C#.
E o "sistema" de cores do jogo é RGB, e até então tava tudo indo muito certo,
porque estava me deparando com códigos em Hex "normais" no jogo como escolher a cor R:255 G:255 B:255 em Hex fica R:FF G:FF B:FF, e aí é só fazer a troca dos valores via Hex, porém eu me deparei com um "sistema" que me deixou perdido até porque sou um mero iniciante rsrs que é o seguinte: as opções de cores do RGB nessa parte do jogo vai somente até o 31, R: 0 ao 31 G: 0 ao 31 B: 0 ao 31 e o código em Hex "gerado" ao escolher a cor no jogo é somente de 2 bytes (inclusive o "slot" para a troca da cor via Hex é só 2 bytes mesmo ) e não 3 como deveria ser por exemplo: no jogo eu escolho R:245 B:130 G:05 em Hex fica F58205 e já nas opções de RGB 31 fica assim R:0 G:0 B:0 e o código Hex fica 0080,
Então... vocês tem alguma ideia de como funciona isso? uma forma existe até porque o cara conseguiu fazer nesse programa antigo não é verdade rsrs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Muito provavelmente a paleta de cores é reduzida (pode ter relação com o processador de video usado, ou simplesmente ser uma maneira compacta de armazenar os dados).

No caso, sendo 5 bits por cor (de 0 a 31) eles podem ser armazenados assim (não necessariamente nesta ordem):

```
   1     2     3     3 componentes de cor
┌────┐┌────┐┌────┐
RRRR RGGG GGBB BBBX
└───────┘ └───────┘  2 bytes
```

Para extrair as cores, a operação seria algo assim:

```
r = ( valor AND 0b1111100000000000 ) / 2048
g = ( valor AND 0b0000011111000000 ) / 64
b = ( valor AND 0b0000000000111110 ) / 2
```

Para gerar cores, basta fazer o inverso, assegurando-se de não "estourar" os bits:

```
cor = ( r * 2048 ) + ( g * 64 ) + ( b * 2 )
```

Ou até mesmo

```
cor = ( r * 2048 ) OR ( g * 64 ) OR ( b * 2 )
```

Ou, se estiver organizado assim:

```
   1     2     3     3 componentes de cor
 ┌────┐┌────┐┌────┐
XRRR RRGG GGGBB BBB
└───────┘ └───────┘  2 bytes
```

Para extrair as cores, a operação seria algo assim:

```
r = ( valor AND 0b0111110000000000 ) / 1024
g = ( valor AND 0b0000001111100000 ) / 32
b = ( valor AND 0b0000000000011111 )
```

E, respectivamente:

```
cor = ( r * 1024 ) + ( g * 32 ) + ( b )
```

(parênteses para facilitar a leitura)

O `X` pode ser ignorado, ou usado como transparência (depende muito da plataforma específica). Em alguns casos, alguma das cores usa um bit a mais, tem que estudar o correto para sua plataforma. O importante é entender a lógica, o resto é ajuste.

Coloquei os valores em binário para leitura apenas, converta para decimal ou hexa no código definitivo. Para converter o `RGB` de volta nos 2 *bytes*, basta multiplicar pelos valores acima em vez de dividir, e fazer um `OR` de bytes, como alternativa à soma dos exemplos.

Comment: Tem um esquema de cor, RGB 565, que usa 6 bits para verde e 5 bits para as outras cores.

Comment: @epx justamente, mencionei no penultimo parágrafo. E em 8 bits tem quem deixe o azul com 2 bits e as outras com 3, pq o azul é o que menos percebemos nuances. Depois, num próximo edit, elaboro melhor.