# Como converter cor de 32(24) bits para 16 bits?

Tags: c#, hexadecimal, rgb

Então pessoal, estou com um problemão rsrs, eu estou criando uma ferramenta de edição de um jogo de futebol de PS2.

E esse jogo tem dois "sistemas" de cores, que são eles:

O RGB "normal" que é; R: 0 a 255, G: 0 ao 255, B: 0 ao 255.

E o, ou acho que é rsrs 5bitRGB; R: 0 ao 31, G: 0 ao 31, B: 0 ao 31.

E é o seguinte, o RGB "normal" eu consigo enviar o valor dele ao textbox. 
E depois de enviado o valor ao textBox, eu salvo esse valor direto no arquivo do jogo via Hex, assim, mudando para a cor que eu quiser, até aí beleza.

Isso dar certo porque... porque o "slot" de bytes dessa cor no arquivo do jogo são realmente 3 bytes, então salvar o valor enviado em Hex do textBox dá certo.

Só que que agora o problema é o 5bitRGB, o "slot" dele no arquivo do jogo é somente de 2 bytes, e não 3, e o colorDialog as opções de cores são "normais" do 0 ao 255 tanto em R, G e B, não tem como fazer só do 0 ao 31, e o problema pior, como enviar o valor do colorDialog nesse formato de 5bitRGB em 2 bytes ao textBox? rsrs será que é possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cores obtidas no ColorDialog estão no formato RGB8888, em que cada cor é representada por 8 bits mais 8 bits para o canal alfa.

Há dois formatos de RGB em 16 bits, RGB555 e RGB565.

No primeiro, as cores são representadas por 5 bits cada, no segundo, as cores RED e BLUE são representados com 5 bits e a cor GREEN com 6.

Como não sei qual o formato em causa, deixo dois métodos que convertem RGB8888 para cada um deles.

RGB565:

```
public ushort Convert8888RGBto565RGB(Color color)
{
    //reduz para 5 bits significativos
    byte r = (byte) (color.R >> 3);
    //reduz para 6 bits significativos
    byte g = (byte)(color.G >> 2);
    //reduz para 5 bits significativos
    byte b = (byte)(color.B >> 3);

    //Junta
    return (ushort)((r << 11) | (g << 5) | b);
}
```

RGB555

```
public ushort Convert8888RGBto555RGB(Color color)
{
    //reduz para 5 bits significativos
    byte r = (byte)(color.R >> 3);
    //reduz para 5 bits significativos
    byte g = (byte)(color.G >> 3);
    //reduz para 5 bits significativos
    byte b = (byte)(color.B >> 3);

    //Junta
    return (ushort)((r << 10) | (g << 5) | b);
}
```

Referências:

- [Working with 16-bit RGB.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390989(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Fiz uns testes aqui e o RGB565 parece ser o correto, porém dessa forma aí ele ainda não dá o valor correto, escolhendo a cor branca ele até dá o valor correto que é 65535 em Hex FFFF. Observei que o RGB555 comtém o valor do 0 ao 32767 enquanto o RGB565 comtém o valor do 32768 que é o correto em Hex 0080 (Cor preto) até o 65535 que também é o correto em Hex FFFF, então penso que esteja faltando um algo a mais para dar o valor correto para converter em Hex.

Comment: O seu comentário está um pouco confuso. Em que situações o RGB565 não dá o valor correcto?

Comment: Então, eu fiz o seguinte pra pegar o valor do colorDialog em RGB565:
            pictureBox1.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
            var c1 = Convert8888RGBto555RGB(colorDialog1.Color);
            var c2 = Convert.ToString(c1);
            MessageBox.Show(c2);
            MessageBox.Show(((int)c1).ToString("X2")); ele dar o valor do normal e e convertido em Hex que é o que quero.

Comment: @ramaral só pra constar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194790/70

Comment: Já conseguir aqui galera valeu aí pela ajuda! :D

Comment: @Bacco O meu código está correcto ou não?

Comment: @ramaral imagino que sim, o autor até aceitou. Só mencionei a outra pra vc estar a par que era o mesmo assunto. Sobre ser 555, 565, pelas imagens postadas deduzo que seja 555 (todos os sliders param no 31), mas ai só o autor testando mesmo.